# How to print list output dynamically in React JS as buttons

Tags: reactjs

Below is the code snippet of my ReactJS component, I'm trying to put the output with a button beside it in a list format. The output which is received in the "axios" get function is from an api and it is in this format: **[{'name': 'i-cc608f4d'}, {'name': 'i-fd608f7c'}, {'name': 'i-fe608f7f'}]**
I want to list these IDs with a button besides it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const pStyle = {
backgroundColor: "#79D3EF",
color: "white"
};

export default class CityContent extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

this.state = {
  citydetail: []
 };
}

componentDidMount() {
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Delhi").then(res => {
  const citydetail = res.data;
  this.setState({ citydetail });
 });
}
render() {
return (
  <div className="content-wrapper">
    <section className="content-header">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <div className="box">
     <div className="box-body">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                  <ul>{this.state.citydetail.state}</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                    </div>
    </section>
  </div>
);
}
```

What should I write to replace `{this.state.citydetail.state}`.
Because currently, it's printing the API output itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="col-md-8">
   <ul>
    {
      this.state.citydetail.map((city) => (
        <li>{city.name}<button>Click</button></li>
    )}
    </ul>
</div>
```

This code will print your output and map will map through that data of citydetail and button beside it.

Comment: You will get a warning here saying div, and buttons are not a valid child for `ul`

Comment: Yes you'll and in that case you can change structure of your html with some css. or ignore that warning. 
Whatever suits you.

Comment: I tried running this, but got below error in chrome developer tool:
"CityContent.jsx?a1a1:43 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.citydetail.map is not a function"
No output on screen

Comment: <div>  should not be added below <ul> tags.

Comment: yes right, for sol we can remove div and print button beside it. 
@SaurabhKumar make sure you have data as array format in your state before mapping it in render.

Comment: @KrinaSoni  The data is in array format, in the description I've already mentioned the data which is coming on page,
I tried the above method too, but still it is showing **this.state.citydetail.map is not a function**.  How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
   <ul>
    {
      this.state.citydetail.map((city, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{city.name}<button>{city.name}</button></li>
    )}
    </ul>
```

**Update**

Set your state like this in `componentDidMount()`

```
this.setState({ citydetail : citydetail });
```

Update 2 (after OP comment)

> I cannot change the format of this output...

try this

```
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Delhi").then(res => {
  const citydetail = res.data;    
  let arrData = JSON.parse(citydetail.replace(/'/g, '"'));

  this.setState({ citydetail: arrData });
 });
```

Comment: Did you add `(city, index)`. Also what do you have here `this.state.citydetail`

Comment: check if your `this.state.citydetail` is an array

Comment: If key and value has same name , the we can do as per question. 
Easier answer will be this.setState({ citydetail : res.data });

Comment: @kiranvj  It is still throwing same error where it says **this.state.citydetail.map is not a function** in chrome developer tool

Comment: What do have in state? Do you have React dev tools? or just `console.log(this.state)` in `render()`, What do you see?

Comment: citydetail:
status: "[{'name': 'i-cc608f4d'}, {'name': 'i-fd608f7c'}, {'name': 'i-
Above is the output I'm getting in console

Comment: console.log(res.data) output:
{status: "[{'name': 'i-cc608f4d'}, {'name': 'i-fd608f7c'}, {'name': 'i-fe608f7f'}]"}
Inside render, console.log(this.state):
{citydetail: "[{'name': 'i-cc608f4d'}, {'name': 'i-fd608f7c'}, {'name': 'i-fe608f7f'}]"}

Comment: Looks like you reponse is not a valid JSON. Can you change all single quotes to doubles in response from backend and check. The JSON should be like `[{"name": "i-cc608f4d"}, {"name": "i-fd608f7c"}, {"name": "i-fe608f7f'}]`

Comment: I cannot change the format of this output, what I can do is I can convert the output to ['i-cc608f4d', 'i-fd608f7c', 'i-fe608f7f']. But If I do that then what to in render method. Ultimately, required output is listing these IDs one below other with button

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Plz see update answer for a work around. hope it works.

Comment: @kiranvj in console log : **citydetail.replace is not a function**

Comment: This is the error coming in console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: citydetail.replace is not a function

Comment: There is something wrong, I suggest you post the full code in a new question, you may get more options

Comment: @kiranvj  https://stackoverflow.com/q/53297439/10617306  Here I've posted the complete code, could you plz check this and suggest

Comment: @kiranvj I'm able to get the output in [{"name": "i-cc608f4d"}, {"name": "i-fd608f7c"}, {"name": "i-fe608f7f'}] format, but still it says **this.state.citydetail.map**is not a function in chrome developer tool

Comment: Try using like `{this.state.citydetail && this.state.citydetail.map((city) => ( ......) }` Also make sure you are initializing the state.citydetail as `citydetail: []`