# Python API Output is not getting formatted in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Below is my ReactJS component written where I want to print the output as list of buttons.

```html
// CityContent.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const pStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "#79D3EF",
  color: "white"
};

export default class CityContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      citydetail: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Delhi").then(res => {
      const citydetail = res.data;
      this.setState({ citydetail });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <section className="content-header">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <div className="box">
                <div className="box-body">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                      <ul>
                        {this.state.citydetail.map(city => (
                          <li>
                            {city.name}
                            <button>{city.name}</button>
                          </li>
                        ))}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The Api used is written in python Boto which returns the list of instances whose code is as follows:

```html
import boto3
import json

Cities = {'Delhi': 'LB1',
          'Hyderabad': 'LB2', 'Mumbai': 'LB3'}


def CityDetail(city):
    client = boto3.client('elb')
    response = client.describe_instance_health(
        LoadBalancerName=Cities[city]
    )
    Instances = dict()
    InstanceList = list()
    for goods in response['InstanceStates']:
        InstanceList.append({"name": goods['InstanceId']})
    print(InstanceList)
```

Api is returning output as :

```
   [{'name': 'i-cc608f4d'}, {'name': 'i-fd608f7c'}, {'name': 'i-fe608f7f'}]
```

I want these IDs to be printed as buttons one below other in ReactJS component.

In the current code when ran doesn't show anything on screen and returns **this.state.citydetail.map** is not a function on chrome console.

Comment: what is the Content-Type of the response?

Comment: It's showing array in console

Comment: If data type is array on browser console (not python console) and no error on browser console, then check your CSS rules.

Comment: There's an error , on console it is showing:
CityContent.jsx?a1a1:44 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.citydetail.map is not a function

Comment: Hit this url directly in browser, what do you see in source (Ctrl + U) http://127.0.0.1:8000/Delhi

Comment: Since I've made a little change in API, now I can see ["i-cc608f4d", "i-fd608f7c", "i-fe608f7f", ""] when I hit the URL. 
Also, if I'm using {this.state.citydetail[0]} in my react component, I'm getting **i-cc608f4d** to be printed in browser, but I need a loop kinda format, because the outputs are dynamic and no. of instances may increase

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Python server is not responding with JSON - try this:

```
Instances = dict()
InstanceList = list()
for goods in response['InstanceStates']:
    InstanceList.append({"name": goods['InstanceId']})
json_str = json.dumps(InstanceList)
print(json_str)
```

Comment: CityContent.jsx?a1a1:44 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.citydetail.map is not a function .
I'm getting above error in ReactJS component

Comment: Making above change made my output like this:  [{"name": "i-cc608f4d"}, {"name": "i-fd608f7c"}, {"name": "i-fe608f7f"}]

Comment: That suggests `this.state.citydetail` is not an array. My guess is that response from API is not of content-type json. What does network tab in chrome dev tools say ? Did you try code from my answer ?
Please add a debug to your get method and check the console
`axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Delhi").then(res => {
      console.log('data', res.data);
      console.log('status', res.status);
      const citydetail = res.data;
      this.setState({ citydetail });
    });`

Comment: I've used your code, and I can see below snippet in chrome console logs :
data
 {status: "[{"name": "i-cc608f4d"}, {"name": "i-fd608f7c"}, {"name": "i-fe608f7f"}]"}
CityContent.jsx?a1a1:27

Comment: But still the " TypeError: this.state.citydetail.map is not a function"  is there is logs.
I believe I'm having issue with this function call in render method, not sure how to fix that in above code

Comment: Not sure why your data is nested in the status hash but in that case:

`const citydetail = res.data.status;`

Comment: Inside render function , if I run console.log(this.state.citydetail) it shows below output: [{"name": "i-cc608f4d"}, {"name": "i-fd608f7c"}, {"name": "i-fe608f7f"}]
I need to know why it is giving :
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.citydetail.map is not a function

Comment: Is there any other alternative which we can use in above code, other than .map

Comment: This [{"name": "i-cc608f4d"}, {"name": "i-fd608f7c"}, {"name": "i-fe608f7f"}]  output - is it string or an array?

We are missing some crucial info here, but let's give it a last chance: `const citydetail = JSON.parse(res.data);`

Comment: [{"name": "i-cc608f4d"}, {"name": "i-fd608f7c"}, {"name": "i-fe608f7f"}] is a list.
I tried doing JSON.parse, it is throwing Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0